# Reverse mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Recall the mean value theorem:

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a,b]$ then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

I am wondering if we can make our choice in reverse. In other words for each $c\in\mathbb{R}$ does there exist an $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $c\in(a,b)$ and $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no, even if the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R$. For instance, if $f(x)=x^3$, then $f'(0)=0$. However, if $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$, you never have $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=0$, since that would imply that $f(a)=f(b)$, but $f$ is injective.